# Show Context Menu after condition Check in Primeng Angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable

I have to show a context menu in a primeng tree table only in the second level.
Is there any way to show the context menu only after some condition check in 
 typescript (angular 4)?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Did you try to use `onContextMenuSelect` event ?

Comment: I also need to show context only when user right clicks  in certain columns..

Answer (score 4):

you can bind onContextMenuSelect event and play with [hide],
I have done it like this.. 
in html...

```
  <p-contextMenu #cm [model]="items" [hidden]="contextMenu"></p-contextMenu>
```

and in ts ..

```
viewDetails(selectedNode) {
    this.contextMenu = false;
    if (selectedNode.children.length == 0) {
        this.contextMenu = false;
    }
    else { this.contextMenu = true;}
}
```

hope it works..

Comment: When it is use this with p-table it doesn't work. If i set  [hidden]="true" or [hidden]="false", whatever always show the context menu.

Comment: are u using ANGULAR 4 PRIMENG @RavindraVairagi ???
I think hidden is deprecated now, need to check on that though.
My solutions work for angular 4 as mentioned in the question so dont downvote :P

Comment: Using angular 5 and PrimeNG version 5.

Comment: Hmmm.. the question is for anguar 4 .. for which my solution works well :)

Answer (score 3):

For me, the best option was to use onContextMenuSelectEvent. First, you need to add it to the tree table

```
<p-treeTable [style]="{'font-size':'1.7rem'}" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFile" (onContextMenuSelect)="contextMenu($event.node, cm)" [contextMenu]="cm" [value]="treeNodeData">
```

and then in the method, you have to check your conditions and show or hide context menu

```
  contextMenu(node, contextMenu){
if(condition){
  contextMenu.hide();
  }
}
```

I hope that it will also work for you.

Comment: Yes, and note that for p-tree it is onNodeContextMenuSelect.https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts

Comment: Worked as mentioned. Thanks Stefan.