# Contextmenu not open in right click in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

By using primeng, when i click right click in a tree node Contextmenu do not open.
Initial code :-

`<p-tree [value]="coaList" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="coa" [contextMenu]="cm" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)"></p-tree>
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="items"></p-contextMenu>`

and in component.ts

```
this.items = [
  { label: 'View', icon: 'fa fa-search', command: (event) => this.viewFile(this.coa) },
  { label: 'Unselect', icon: 'fa fa-close', command: (event) => this.viewFile(this.coa) }
];
```

where import in component.ts is :-

```
import { TreeNode, MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
```

and in module 
`import { ContextMenuModule } from primeng/components/contextmenu/contextmenu';`

Whats wrong i'm doing?

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: No. Nothing in Console. Also, other events work absolutely fine.

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235291/show-context-menu-after-condition-check-in-primeng-angular-4/49879902?noredirect=1#comment95212013_49879902

Especially I mean about using (onNodeContextMenuSelect) event to show context menu.

Comment: problem found already,,Its actually css problem. Sorry for late comment.