# Hide Primeng context menu with a condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

I'm trying to hide the context menu when there is a condition applied. I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235291/show-context-menu-after-condition-check-in-primeng-angular-4?answertab=oldest#tab-top) post and followed through with it but still, the context menu is showing. I'm trying to add context menu to p-table and I have a condition where if there are no options available then I want to hide context menu but when I'm calling hide() method on context menu it's not working. below are the code snippets of what I did so far.

In .html file

```
<p-table #table (onContextMenuSelect)="onContextMenuSelect($event, tableContextMenu)" [contextMenu]="tableContextMenu"> </p-table>
<p-contextMenu #tableContextMenu appendTo="body" [model]="contextMenus"></p-contextMenu>
```

In .ts file

```
 public onContextMenuSelect(event, contextMenu){
     if(this.loadContextMenu){
     contextMenu.hide();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `(onContextMenuSelect)` to `contextmenu` will trigger `contextMenu.hide();` if condition is matched.

```
<p-table #table (contextmenu)="onContextMenuSelect($event, tableContextMenu)" [contextMenu]="tableContextMenu"> </p-table>
```